# Cannot load tensorflow_hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

after writing import tensorflow_hub, the following error emerges:

```
class LatestModuleExporter(tf.estimator.Exporter):
```

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.estimator.estimator_lib' has no attribute 'Exporter'

I'm using python 3.6 with tensorflow 1.7 on Windows 10

thanks!

Answer (score 14):

You should have at least tensorflow 1.7.0, upgrate by:

```
pip install "tensorflow>=1.7.0"
pip install tensorflow-hub
```

and then:

```
pip install tensorflow-hub
```

source: [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/installation)

Answer (score 2):

You can reinstall TensorFlow_hub:

```
pip install ipykernel

pip install tensorflow_hub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your python3 runtime is not really running with tensorflow 1.7. That attribute exists since tensorflow 1.4. I suspect some mismatch between python2/3 environment, mismatch installing with pip/pip3 or an issue with installing both tensorflow and tf-nightly pip packages.

You can double check with:

```
$ python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Just simple run following line on cell.

import tensorflow_hub as hub